# What is the identity for $ab \equiv 2ab \pmod 7$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Using elements $1, 3, 5$ write out a Cayley table. The operation for the table is $ab = 2ab$. For example $5 \cdot 4= 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 2= 40 \equiv 5 \pmod 7$.  What is the identity for this table?

Answer (score 0):

It is the inverse of $2$ modulo $7$, which is $\boxed{4}$. Indeed, for any $b \in \mathbb Z$, observe that:
\begin{align*}
4 * b &= 2(4b) \pmod 7 \\
&= (8)b \pmod 7 \\
&= (7+1)b \pmod 7 \\
&= b \pmod 7
\end{align*}